# Cannot find MPI library even after it is specified explicitly

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, mpi

I'm trying to compile [SimulateQCD](https://github.com/LatticeQCD/SIMULATeQCD) however I'm struggling to figure out how to tell cmake where to look for the MPI libraries. I have installed `openmpi-devel` and found the header files. I have tried increasing degrees of specificity but it seems to stick [here](https://github.com/LatticeQCD/SIMULATeQCD). Now that I have explicitly told it to look and it still doesn't find MPI I'm at a loss. I haven't used CMake before so I'm also having a bit of trouble interpreting the rather arcane messages it produces.

```
[root@rockylinux build]# cmake ../simulateqcd/ -DARCHITECTURE="70" -DUSE_GPU_AWARE_MPI=ON -DUSE_GPU_P2P=ON -DMPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES=/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -DMPI_CXX_HEADER_DIR=/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64 -DMPI_C_COMPILER=/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpicxx
-- Using git version 43e2518
-- Using CUDA backend
-- Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib_LIBRARY MPI_CXX_WORKS) (Required is at least version "3.1")
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_CXX_FOUND) (Required is at least version
  "3.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1742 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/opt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

# Check Compiler Paths

[root@rockylinux build]# /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpicxx --showme:compile
-I/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64
[root@rockylinux build]# /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpicxx --showme:link
-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -L/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -lmpi_cxx -lmpi
```

Comment: Try `-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mpicxx`. That eliminates the need to specify all that library stuff. Also: you can put `find_package( MPI )` inyour cmake file and whatever is in path will be found.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindMPI.html), variable `MPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES` is the **list** of **libraries names**. Assigning to this variable a **directory** - `/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib` - is meaningless. If you want to hint CMake about the library location, then set `MPI_<lib_name>_LIBRARY` variable (substring `<lib_name>` should be listed in `MPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES` variable).